# Crowded contour plot lines

Tags: pgfplots

Many thanks to [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar) for getting me this far.  He made an immense difference with a single character [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244228/contour-plots-in-groupplot) :)

I have a contour plot that is, to be frank, ugly.  The surface it was generated from was not very smooth.  In the picture below, it's (obviously) the one on the right

[image]

I've been looking for a way to reduce the number of labels, and the closest I've found is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94247/too-many-contour-labels-in-contour-plots) solution...but it doesn't get me there.

The code to produce the plots is below.  The data files can be found on pastebin.  CAG_Contour.dat is [here](http://pastebin.com/TzJJ7KZF) and PPR_Contour.dat is [here](http://pastebin.com/g1a86UBr)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=2 by 1,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                ylabels at=edge left},
                xlabel = {\footnotesize $\alpha_{++}$},
                ylabel = {\footnotesize Departure Rate}]
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Come and Go}]
                \addplot[contour/draw color=black, 
                         contour/label distance=125pt, 
                                 contour/every contour label/.append style={every node/.style={black!50,fill=white}},
                                 contour prepared, 
                                 contour prepared format=matlab]
                         table {CAG_Contour.dat};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}]
                \addplot[contour/draw color=black, 
                         contour/label distance=400pt, 
                                 contour/every contour label/.append style={every node/.style={black!50,fill=white}},
                                 contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab]
                         table {PPR_Contour.dat};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If anyone has any suggestions for how to improve the appearance of the contour plot on the right I would be very grateful.